# Webform Redirect Hook

Tags: webforms, redirection

I built a module that submits the webform data to a soap api. The API an take a while to respond (out of my control), so what I'm looking for is a redirection hook, so I can go Submit->Force Redirection->submit to api.

Users are hitting submit more than once due to the api response time (understandably)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the double click  on submit using the below jQuery code.

```
$('#formid').submit(function(){
    $(this).children('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Now you can use the below code to alter submit of webform in your custom module

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */
function mywebform_extra_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Add extra submit for a particular Webform node:
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_44') {


    // Add the submit handler after the existing Webform submit handler,
    // but before the second Webform handler. Pop off the first one and add
    // ours second.
   $form['#submit'][] = 'mywebform_extra_validate_44';
  }
}

/**
 * Submit handler for Webform ID #44.
 */
function mywebform_extra_submit_44(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;


  // Now you can perform here api request and redirect 
}
```

Hope it will help you.